# Angularjs : Using common service in different modules

Tags: angularjs, angularjs-service, angularjs-factory, angularjs-provider

I am trying to use the same **service** for different modules. There are many modules so i tried to inject them in a parent module. Something like this:

```
var app=angular.module('myapp',['module_1','module_2',....,'module_n']);


var module_1=angular.module('myapp1',[]);
var module_2=angular.module('myapp2',[]);
var module_3=angular.module('myapp3',[]);
.
.
.
var module_n=angular.module('myappN',[]);
```

and the service which is common to all the *n* modules is like this:

```
.service('myService',function(){
...doing something here...
});
```

Now I am not able to figure out how to use this service for all the submodules.
With which module should I associate this *service* ?
I tried doing `app.service('myService',function(){...})`, but it did'nt work.
Where am I going wrong?

**EDIT 1:**
Moreover I am trying to share a variable with all these submodules using the *service*. I am not sure if, I am doing the right thing by using a *service* for sharing variable or should I use a *Provider* or *Factory* for this job.

**EDIT 2:**
I found these links, but I could not grasp the answer. Refer to them and please provide my answer
[How to share a variable between multiple modules in AngularJS](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/33921344/how-to-share-a-variable-between-multiple-modules-in-angularjs)
[Passing variable between controllers which are on different modules](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/22235301/passing-variable-between-controllers-which-are-on-different-modules)

Comment: http://stackoverflow.com/questions/16725392/share-a-single-service-between-multiple-angular-js-apps

Answer (score 0):

Lets suppose you want to build a `Service` to share a certain variable between two `Controllers`. You should be able to use your `Service` doing the following:

**MyService.js**

```
// Lets suppose you want to share a certain variable between controllers
angular
.module('myApp')
.service('myService', function () {

  // If you wish you can inject and use $scope
  var vm = this;
  // Variable to share
  vm.sharedItem;

  // Method to set a certain value into a variable
  function setItem(item){
   vm.sharedItem = item;
  }

  // Method to get that variable
  function getItem(){
    return vm.sharedItem;
  }

  // Exposing your methods
  return {
    setItem     : setItem
    getItem     : getItem
  }
});
```

**SetController.js**

```
angular
.module('myApp')
.controller('SetController', SetController);

  // Inject your Service
  function SetController(myService) {

    var vm = this;
    // variable used to set the value
    vm.setMe = 'hello';

    // Call `setItem()` method from `myService` -> sharedItem will get setMe value
    myService.setItem(vm.setMe);

    console.log("Set shared item "+vm.setMe);
  };
```

**GetController.js**:

```
angular
.module('myApp')
.controller('GetController', GetController);

  // Inject your Service
  function SetController(myService) {

    var vm = this;
    // variable used to get shared the value
    vm.getMe= null;

    /* Call `getItem()` method from `myService` to get the shared 
     * value and assign it to `getMe`*/
    vm.getMe = myService.getItem();

    console.log("Got shared item "+vm.getMe);
};
```

I remind you can access `this.var` in your view using `controllerName.var`. It is a good solution to make sure you are using a certain controller. You can always use `$scope` if you wish.

I hope I've been helpful.

Comment: very well said. But my doubt is, how to share `myService` to the controllers, when they are in different modules? What i have researched draws me towards making a parent module whose dependencies are the modules which need to share the common `myService`.Make the service a part of parent module and then inject the service in those child modules. But i am not sure how exactly to execute it

Comment: Why don't you just inject the service into the childs?

Comment: I tried to do the same, although I was successful in using the service but was still not able to share the variable in those child modules, using that service.